How modern cars wire their cameras?
I'm looking into ADAS and selfdrive technologies and I couldn't find reliable information about how the cameras and sensors are put together in the car.
So how are the cameras and sensors wired on the car? Which physical and data protocols are being used?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Did you try enquiring directly to manufacturers like Tesla and Alphabet (a separate entity of Google) using WAYMO driverless taxis?

Yeah, I was only able to find out that Tesla uses MIPI Cameras
